# Drawable folder for 8 inch tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in an android application and I want to support my application in all devices. But I don't know from which drawable folder **8 inch tablet** takes images.

```
"drawable-mdpi" for mobiles, containing 320px-width images   
"drawable-hdpi" for mobiles, containing 480px-width images  
"drawable-xhdpi" for mobiles, containing 720px-width images  
"drawable-sw600dp" for 7'' tablets, containing 600px-width images  
"drawable-sw720dp" for 10'' tablets, containing 720px-width images    
 ????             for 8'' tablets
```

Comment: [Have you read this?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) There is a table with qulifiers description and priority.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You can use : `"drawable-sw720dp"` for `10'' tablets`, containing `720px-width images"` for the `8" Tablet` .

For more info you can refer here , as 8" is reside between 7-10 Range so that you can use 10" drawable folder

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: How create **drawable** folder for 8.9' tablets? Now 8.9' tablets takes images from **drawable-sw720dp**, but those images are huge for those tablets.

Answer (score 3):

"**drawable-sw600dp**" for **7'' tablets**, containing 600px-width images

"**drawable-sw600dp**" is the folder that applies the drawable properties of device with minimum 600dp width.

So you dont need to worry about it.The android system will automatically suites drawable from sw600dp to 8 Inch Tablets

Have a Nice Day ....

Answer (score 2):

The qualifiers hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi describes the screen density of the device, not the size of screen. From the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview)

```
            The better practice is to put the following drawables
           // for Phones
            drawable-ldpi
            drawable-mdpi
            drawable-hdpi

          //for 7 inch tablets
              drawable-large-mdpi
              drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)

         // for 10 inch tablets
             drawable-xlarge-mdpi
```

Comment: 7 inch tablets, comes into the largescreen category, and 8 inch tablets falls into xlarge-screen. so use following folders for both these:

1 drawable-large

2 drawable-xlarge

Answer (score 0):

The drawable for 8" inches should be implemented if the App uses large background images where should be taken in a serious importance for memory allocation. 
U can easily categorize your Drawables to large-mdpi, large-xhdpi , large-port-xhdpi(..) but u are in a situation where u delete the small , normal large and u implementing a swallest width of 600, 720 as any android delevopers will customize early or later.. I really suggest to implement an sw800 where has 1280 x 800!!! and also to make sure in your code to have an ifstatement where directly speaks throw the DisplayMetrics.Density and implements == to 800 widthPixels... This will give an HD performance if the images are recycling and are on in InBitmap to retain instance..