# Not displaying big icons in galaxy tab 3 in my android application

Tags: android, android-drawable

Hi in the below layout icon displaying small and as well as icons not occupying full screen.I want to occupy the icon in full screen and icon should be in bigger size.!

If I am using small mobiles it occupying full screen and icons also displaying correct size.when I am installing my app in this device it's giving two problems.

Can any one help me from this issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: read about `drawable` [folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517389/android-understanding-drawable-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for explicit information.

Any android phone has one of this six screen densities.

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).

mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). 
        (This is the baseline density.)

hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).

xhdpi   Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

xxhdpi  Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi).

xxxhdpi Resources for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi).
        Use this for the launcher icon only, see note above.
```

Create icons of different sizes for different screen resolutions and put those icons to `yourProject/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi or -hdpi or -xhdpi or -xxhdip` folder.

Comment: @user1 are you sure you have given a same name for a single icon in all drawable folders?

Comment: yes I gave same name.But I have small doubt your device isn't compatible with this version android this o.s version is not selecting or anything wrong

Comment: @user1 i'm not getting you, would you please explain?\

Comment: After uploading into play store.Now I am try to app from play store using this Galaxy tab 3 device. but it showing this message your device isn't compatible with this version android then I was copied the .Apk file I was downloaded this app into my device is there is any reason for this version I am getting small icons ?.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that even though the tablet has high resolution, it still has low density due to its large screen size. So, the tablet is picking the image from low density folder which makes it look small on large scree.

The discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368469/drawable-folder-for-8-inch-tablets) sheds some light on the issue. Basically you are required to create separate drawable folders for tablet's width. Ex. `drawable-sw600dp` and `drawable-sw720dp` etc.

Refer [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) for more details.

Comment: can you please tell me the image size for drawable-sw600dp and drawable-sw720dp and where I want to create this folders

Comment: A 720p mobile will be classified as xhdpi so i think for sw720 you can use xhdpi resources and for sw600 hdpi resources should work.